# cant recognize gesture inside uitableview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview

i have uitableview within uitableview (in its cell, like pulse app), and for some reason that i dont think its relevant, i need to know when user try to go left when he is in the first cell of the inner uitableview.

i tryed adding following code to outer/inner table, outer, inner cell, imageview in inner table cell, and i cant get it to work.. method - (void)handleSwipeFrom:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {} just doesnt get invoked...

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                     initWithTarget:self
                                     action:@selector(handleSwipeFrom:)];
[gesture setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];
[tableViewCell addGestureRecognizer:gesture];
[gesture release];
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LOL my tableview was rotated and swipe left was actually swipe down.. it all works now

Answer (score 1):

Consider using UIScrollView within each UITableViewCell. The delegate of a UIScrollView tracks position, and you can set paging to enabled in order to make it snap. But if you would like to stick with a UITableView inside of a UITableView, the second part of [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4723/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-2) covers nested tableviews. And the [first part](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4680/how-to-make-an-interface-with-horizontal-tables-like-the-pulse-news-app-part-1) might be useful as well.

Comment: uitableview inherits from uiscrollview so delegates of uiscrollviews work, but i dont know how to help myself with it, as i need to know when users go left in the first cell.. if(swipe.left && tableLoc[0,0] would work (but cant get swipe recognizers to work).. but how to help myself with position?

thanks for tutoritals btw, will check them out